# TableView deselectRowAtIndexPath does not call setHighlighted

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to change states of the label in my table view cell.
I want to keep a cell selected while I push a different view controller and move back to the view controller with my tableview.
When I select another row I want to remove highlight of previously selected row's lable (deselect the previously selected row) and Highlight the current row's label.
Is `- (void)deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated` supposed to call `- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated` with highlighted 'NO' for that Cell ?
Note: I'm not UITableViewController.

Comment: When using a UITableViewController, the default is to clear a selection when the view appears following a pop. However you say you are not using that, which I assume means its a UITableView in your own controller. Are you finding that the cell does not stay selected? I would have thought that on select, it stays selected unless you clear it yourself or do a reloadData. Selecting a different row should automatically deselect and select the new one if you have set the table to single select. So this should be happening by default unless you are reloading the cells in one of your delegates?

Answer (score 0):

Keep cell selected:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selected = YES;
    //Other code 
}
```

Ensure that the class cell don't have selected = NONE in interface builder.
[image]

Unselect last row:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *currentSelectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (currentSelectedIndexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.selected = NO;
    }
    return indexPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should set TableviewCell properly [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];  in method :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Other then this, you can set custom background of selected cell by

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.97 alpha:1.0];
bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

For Your highlight selected cell problem, you can use Simple flag like

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSIndexPath *ip= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:flagForLastSelectedRow inSection:0];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    flagForLastSelectedRow=indexPath.row;
}
```